# Synchronizing var instantiation upon multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to sync a var instantiation like this one:

```
Object o = new Object();
String s = null;

void getS() {
  if (s != null) {
    return s;
  }
  // multiple threads stopping here
  // maybe using readwritelock? write.lock?
  syncronize(o) {
    // if previous thread stopped by sync block
    // completed before, bypass this
    if (s != null) {
      return s;
    }

    // no one before, instantiate s
    s = "abc";
  }
  return s; 
}
```

Is there a better way to handle a single time instantiation of var s? Maybe using locks?

Comment: Take a look at singleton pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern. You might need a wrapper around that `String`.

Comment: Why can't you make `s` `static`?

Comment: Making it static i've multiple thread calculating s value, only the first one will instantiate it, wasting other threads time, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: What you have is a variant of [double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). If it is indeed meant for an instance variable, take care to use `volatile` if you use something more complicated than Strings (see the article to see why). For singletons, there are [better ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) to implement it.

Comment: Consider s = "abc" an example, i can have a time and cpu consuming method there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `s` volatile

```
volatile String s;
```

and we'll get a classic double-checked locking design pattern implementation. Patterns are formalized best practices so you dont need to try and further improve this code.

BTW the example with lazy String initialization makes no sense, it should be an expensive to create Object

Comment: I assume the use of the `String` is only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Reading @kiheru link, i've found that's this is the best way. Maybe using static helper.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest to write:

```
private Foo foo;
public synchronized Foo getFoo() {
    if (foo == null) {
        foo = new Foo();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

The downside is that you have synchronization happen every time you access this property, even though synchronization is only needed the first time.

Google "double checked locking in java" for lots of information about ways that you can accomplish the same thing, but with less locking (and therefore potentially better performance).

Comment: Surely sync block in get method is not what i want.

Comment: Synchronization is required if you are going to do lazy (non-static, after class  creation) initialization. There are a bunch of different patterns you can use for the synchronization - I just showed the simplest. Nearly as simple is to synchronize on a separate object. Correctly implemented double-checked locking-type patterns are more complex but require less synchronization at runtime.

Comment: Sometimes simple is better, sometimes faster (and more complex) is better. You get to pick.

Comment: It's always better to have localized lock like the OP has.  If there were more synchronized methods, this would increase lock contention unnecessarily.

Comment: No such thing as "always." If there are no other synchronized methods, then a separate lock object is an extra piece of memory/garbage. Also, the class may not be performance-sensitive and simpler might be a better choice. I would wholeheartedly agree that a separate lock object is "usually" a better choice.